# PHP Daemon Auto Restart on Fail

Tags: linux, batch-file, daemon, php-5.3

I have a PHP script running as a daemon. Every once in a while, I want the script to take a break and restart to clear up the memory usage when it receives the signal.

I've been looking at shell_exec(); to kill and restart the PHP script, however I was wondering if there was a cleaner method. I've also looked at wrapping the PHP script in a batch, and restarting it if needed, but I am only knowledgeable in PHP.

```
declare(ticks = 1);
    $processID = pcntl_fork();
    if ( $processID == -1 ) {
        echo "\n Error:  The process failed to fork. \n";
    } else if ( $processID ) {
        exit;
    } else {
    }
    if ( posix_setsid() == -1 ) {
        echo "\n Error: Unable to detach from the terminal window. \n";
    }
    $posixProcessID = posix_getpid();
    $filePointer = fopen( "/var/run/addy.pid" , "w" );
    fwrite( $filePointer , $posixProcessID );
    fclose( $filePointer );


gc_enable();
while (true) {

sleep(1);

print "debug: memory_get_peak_usage: ".memory_get_peak_usage()." debug: memory_get_usage: ".memory_get_usage()."\n";

   // STUFF GOES HERE

unset($array);
gc_collect_cycles();
    }
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to have a BASH script that would run your daemon.

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ 1 ]; do
  ./my_php_daemon
done
```

Then just exit your php daemon whenever you want it to restart.

Comment: I enjoy that this is the only answer, it's simple and solves the problem, and it gets -1 with no comment or alternate proposed...

Comment: I agree with you. I like this answer. However, I went another route! ps: I didn't down vote this answer.

Comment: I didn't think you did, I figure someone trolled along and said "pssh how un-elegant, a bash script while loop".  Simplicity does the trick!